# Is it possible to downgrade 1.9.3.3 version to 1.9.3.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, version

How to downgrade the the version from 1.9.3.3 to 1.9.3.2.. Is there any possibilities to do this?

Comment: Why would you like to downgrade? As @paj states in his answer, the update contains security updates. If you encountered any issues, maybe we can help you fix those instead of downgrading to a more unsafe release.

Comment: I was installing extension of Desktop Notification for admin when order placed. It was compatible upto 1.9.2 only. Even though I installed and configured but am not getting any notification in my desktop. I don't know what mistake am doing. so only @ mizuti

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.9.3.3 was a security update, you *should* be able to downgrade by replacing all the core code from 1.9.3.3 with 1.9.3.2.

> **DO NOT do this if you have modified any Magento core code or themes on your live server.**
>
> **BACKUP your database and test this in a DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT first**

You can download the core code from the [Magento download page](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download), you will find 1.9.3.2 under the 1.x release archives.

Unzip the core files to a temp folder on your server and then copy the files over your 1.9.3.3 installation.

- put your magento store into maintenance mode and disable the cache
- copy the 1932 files

rsync -avI --exclude=app/etc/local.xml  --exclude=app/etc/config.xml --exclude=favicon.ico --exclude=index.php --exclude=.htaccess  /tempolder/magento1932/ /pathtomageno/magento1933/

- reset file permissions
- remove maintenance flag
- test